# Java division using BigDecimal

Tags: java, rounding, division, bigdecimal

I am a newbie on java so I need your help on a project I am working on! 
I defined some counters, these are what will I use:

```
int[] acceptCounters = {};
int[] acceptFailCounters = {};
```

Then I wrote them like that to get connection with database, and see the results:

```
acceptCounters = guiops.getOfferStatitics(conn, "WS_GET_OFFER_ACCEPT");
acceptFailCounters = guiops.getOfferStatitics(conn, "WS_GET_OFFER_ACCEPT_PURCHASE_FAILED");*
```

I get the results like that (I deleted the HTML parts):

```
        *__html parts__*

        <%
            for (int i = 0; i < acceptCounters.length; i++) {
        %>
```

***html parts***

```
        <%=formatter.format((new BigDecimal(acceptCounters[i] + acceptFailCounters[i])).longValue())%>

        <%
            }
        %>
```

These are OK. What I want to find is the success ratio, which is **acceptCounters / (acceptCounters + acceptFailCounters)** and to see 2 decimal digits. To keep them in the same format, I wrote the Java codes like this:

***html parts***

```
        <%
            for (int i = 0; i < acceptCounters.length; i++) {
        %>
```

***html parts***

```
        <%=formatter.format((new BigDecimal(acceptCounters[i] /(acceptCounters[i] + acceptFailCounters[i]))).longValue())%>

        <%
            }
        %>
```

But all I see as a result is 0. It should be close to 0.75 or sth. Can you help me to find success ratio? I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Why do you use `BigDecimal` at all? And read about integer division (the result will be integer as well).

Comment: Use JSTL and format https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm  - there should not be java in you jsp

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal has its own divide method. you may use like this:

```
formatter.format((new BigDecimal(acceptCounters[i]).divide(new BigDecimal(acceptCounters[i]),3)).add(new BigDecimal(acceptFailCounters[i]));
```

> `BigDecimal java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal divisor, int roundingMode)`
>
> Returns a BigDecimal whose value is (this / divisor), and whose scale is this.scale(). If rounding must be performed to generate a result with the given scale, the specified rounding mode is applied.

Comment: @Cheatan chadha I have 2 questions for that: why did you wrote ,3 ? and does the operation sequence valid here? I mean first summation of fail and accept and then the division: accept / (accept+fail).  Thank you.

Comment: I have used 3 here for rounding mode because I want the division result upto3 decimal places you can modify it as per your requirement. And operation sequence does matter remember the simple BODMAS rule.

Comment: Can you clarify this statement: ** BigDecimal java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal divisor, int roundingMode) ** because I got error. I imported the lib: 
<%@page import="java.math.BigDecimal"%> , So I wrote the bold part like this: BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal divisor, int roundingMode)   . But I got error, it says delete the divisor and delete the int ; but ofc it gives error again when I delete them since roundingMode cannot be resolved to a variable.. As I said I am completely newbie so I need help and clarification. Thank you :)

Comment: It is just the syntax part, you need not copy paste this. This is just for your reference. I have already customized the formatter as per your need. If you are facing the issue in that then do let me know the actual error you are getting. Thanks.

Comment: I get this error: "The constructor BigDecimal(int, int) is undefined" , so I see that I need to reorganize the definition part, but I couldnt define it.

Comment: you are trying to initialize the BigDecimal constructor with two arguments although it will take only single parameter. Try new BigDecimal("single value here");

Comment: @frunsciante: what about reading and trying to understand the [documentation for BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)? Should answer all your questions. Would have avoided the (int, int) followup question, would have shown you (how) to use divide() etc.